# How to solve Unidentified Error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

My game is live in app  Store. While checking for the `Flurry` analytics
 Errors I got the following reports:      + 126

```
> The full Stack Trace of the crash are: Full Stack Trace: 0  
> CoreFoundation                      0x26030f87 <redacted> + 126 1  
> libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3378fc77 _objc_exception_throw +
> 38 2   UIKit                               0x29790df3
> -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 2910 3   UIKit                               0x297928cb <redacted> + 258 4  
> UIKit                               0x2958f615 -[UIViewController
> presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 196 5  
> BrainMemoryMaster1                  0x0010b44b -[Levels
> interstitial:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:] + 106 6  
> BrainMemoryMaster1                  0x001b9e44 -[GADInterstitial
> slot:didFailToLoadAdContentWithError:] + 260 7   BrainMemoryMaster1   
> 0x001f31ec -[GADExtras .cxx_destruct] + 2804 8   BrainMemoryMaster1   
> 0x001b9dc0 -[GADInterstitial slot:didFailToLoadAdContentWithError:] +
> 128 9   BrainMemoryMaster1                  0x001e0690 -[GADSlot
> adFailedToReceiveContentWithError:] + 84 10  BrainMemoryMaster1       
> 0x00200960 -[GADSlot
> didFailToReceiveAdWithError:shouldCancelPendingActions:] + 500 11 
> BrainMemoryMaster1                  0x001c1da8 -[GADSlot
> adFetcher:didFailToFetchAd:withError:responseCode:] + 148 12 
> BrainMemoryMaster1                  0x001de9d8 -[GADAdFetcher
> resourceFailedToLoadWithError:responseCode:] + 116 13 
> BrainMemoryMaster1                  0x001dfc7c -[GADAdFetcher
> connection:loadDidFail:httpStatusCode:] + 564 14  BrainMemoryMaster1  
> 0x001e6258 -[GADURLConnection connection:didFailWithError:] + 284 15 
> CFNetwork                           0x25b8d50d <redacted> + 56 16 
> CFNetwork                           0x25b8d4c7
> -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 182 17  CFNetwork                           0x25b8d5e9
> -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:] + 36 18  CFNetwork                           0x25b7b225 <redacted> + 84 19 
> CFNetwork                           0x25b4052b <redacted> + 86 20 
> CFNetwork                           0x25b3ee75 <redacted> + 60 21 
> CFNetwork                           0x25a939f9 <redacted> + 60 22 
> CoreFoundation                      0x25f42821 _CFArrayApplyFunction +
> 36 23  CFNetwork                           0x25a938b3 <redacted> + 182
> 24  CFNetwork                           0x25a93779 <redacted> + 216 25
> CFNetwork                           0x25a93615 <redacted> + 48 26 
> CoreFoundation                      0x25ff7807 <redacted> + 14 27 
> CoreFoundation                      0x25ff6c1b <redacted> + 222 28 
> CoreFoundation                      0x25ff5299 <redacted> + 768 29 
> CoreFoundation                      0x25f42db1 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific +
> 476 30  CoreFoundation                      0x25f42bc3
> _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106 31  GraphicsServices                    0x2d2ce051 _GSEventRunModal + 136 32  UIKit                           
> 0x2950ea31 _UIApplicationMain + 1440 33  BrainMemoryMaster1           
> 0x000cc347 -[UIView sd_removeImageLoadOperationWithKey:] + 158 34 
> libdyld.dylib                       0x33d2baaf <redacted> + 2
```

Can any one say me what exactly the error is?

Comment: The top of the stack is showing a thrown exception.  What is the thrown exception?

Comment: redacted + 126 is in the top of the stack.it is the exception.

Can i know that what exactly is "redacted +126"?

Comment: That's just part of the internal exception handling mechanism.  The crash report should include an exception description, above the start of the stack trace.